# subir y descargar archivos con mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas compañeros estoy por terminar un proyecto solo me queda el ultimo paso que es poder adjuntar un archivo (jpg,docx,xls) e insertarlo en mi base de datos para luego poder visualizar el archivo y descargarlo desde proyecto que conectan a la misma base de datos, este es mi codigo donde tengo mi input type file, todos los demas campos se insertan correctamente, favor solicito ayuda a ver si puedo de estar manera o como me aconsejan, ya que intente subiendolo a una carpeta de mi proyecto, pero luego no puedo realizar la descarga desde otro proyecto distinto, muchas gracias

Adjunto mi codigo

```
    <form name="frmNotification" id="frmNotification" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post" >
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="autor">Asunto </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="asunto" id="asunto" placeholder="Ingresa Asunto" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="mensaje">Mensaje </label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="3" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <select  name="nombres" id="nombres" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Destinatario...</option>
                <?php
                $query="SELECT * FROM datos";
                $result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['usuario'].'">'.$row['usuario'].'</option>';
                  }
                 ?>
                 </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="prioridad">Prioridad :</label>
                <select name="prioridad" id="prioridad" class="form-control">
                <option value="opcion1">--</option>
                <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                <option value="Media">Media</option>
                <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="fecha">Plazo </label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="estado">Estado :</label>
                <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control">
                <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                </select>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="form-group
 //SE CARGA ARCHIVO <input type="file" name="archivo">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit" name="add" id="btn-send" value="Enviar">
                </div>

              </form>            

          </p>

        </div>

    </div>
//CONSULTA INSERT
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $autor=$_SESSION['nombredelusuario'];  
        $asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
        $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];
    $prioridad=$_POST['prioridad'];
    $destinatario=$_POST['nombres'];
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
    $estado=$_POST['estado'];
    $comentario=$_POST['comentario'];
    $archivo=$_POST['archivo'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];



        $insertarDatos = "INSERT INTO mensaje VALUES( '$autor',
                                                  '$asunto',
                                                        '$mensaje',
                                                  '$prioridad',
                                                  '$destinatario',
                                                  '$fecha',
                                                  '$estado',
                                                  '$comentario',
                                                  '$archivo',
                                                  '$id')";

        $ejecutarInsertar = mysqli_query($mysqli, $insertarDatos);
        if(!$ejecutarInsertar){
            echo"Error En la linea de sql";
            }
        header("location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

[image: Asi se ve el formulario]

Comment: Es mejor guardar los archivos en carpetas, en la base de datos, si quieres, guardas sólo el nombre y/o la ruta de cada archivo, para saber dónde buscarlo. Optar por guardar archivos en la BD no es la mejor opción. ¿Qué problemas tuviste al intentarlo con archivos en carpetas? Te animaría a que retomes tu idea inicial y si hay algún error te echaremos una mano.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta estimado, el problema que tuve es que quiero realizar la descarga de esos archivos desde otro proyecto que no se encuentra la carpeta, solo podia visualizar la informacion de los archivos en la bd

Comment: Pero, dando los permisos adecuados no hay ningún problema en obtener archivos desde otro destino, basta con usar la URL donde se encuentra ubicado el archivo.

Comment: Lo intentare nuevamente, usando la URL que corresponde y le comento, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendable guardar archivos en la base de datos SQL, después de todo ya tienes una base de datos de archivos: el sistema de archivos. Existen además implicaciones de seguridad y de rendimiento muy importantes y que deberías estudiar antes de seguir queriendo hacerlo:

- Los backups serían eternos, y eso puede ser un problema muy grave si los quieres hacer en una sola transacción (y si quieres integridad entonces quieres). Se podría atenuar el problema teniendo un servidor esclavo y haciendo los backups en él. Curiosamente el proceso de backup sería más simple porque sólo habría que guardar la base de datos y no habría que copiar los archivos también.
- El rendimiento decaería mucho según qué consultas hagas. En cualquier caso no deberías meter los archivos en ningún sistema de conversión a objetos, porque entonces podrías estar leyendo el archivo cada vez que miras otras tablas relacionadas.
- Permitir que cualquiera pueda subir archivos desde internet puede ser muy peligroso. Te quedarás sin disco muy rápidamente y la base de datos se podría corromper. Este problema también existe si utilizas el sistema de archivos, pero al menos puedes tener una partición específica para esto y así evitas corrupción de datos.

Dicho esto, las bases de datos pueden almacenar datos binarios en campos. Cada base de datos ofrece soluciones distintas a esto, algunas más estándar que otras. Por tu script parece que utilizas MySQL o MariaDB así que el tipo de datos que probablemente querrás utilizar sería VARBINARY. Puedes ver la documentación de MySQL [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) y la de MariaDB [aquí](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/varbinary/).

En ambos casos VARBINARY tiene las mismas limitaciones de tamaño que VARCHAR (aunque medido en bytes), que en estas bases de datos puede ser una cifra demasiado baja para almacenar archivos: 65535 en MySQL y 65532 en MariaDB, es decir, unos bytes menos de 64kiB.

Otros motores de base de datos sí pueden almacenar archivos más grandes, como OracleDB, pero sigue siendo recomendable utilizar el sistema de archivos por seguridad y rendimiento.